# How to retrieve the DOM data from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have below code to develop a chrome extension.

#### manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "maskMe",
  "description": "This extension mask your profile section",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "24": "foto/icon_24.png",
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "foto/icon_32.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
  },
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["js/script.js","js/jquery.min.js"]
  }]
}
```

#### background.js

```
debugger;
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "maskkkk"});

function doStuffWithDOM(domContent) {
    console.log("I received the following DOM content:\n" + domContent);
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    console.log('will this run bg scrpt blow');
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { text: "report_back" },doStuffWithDOM);
});
```

#### script.js

```
debugger;
/* Listen for messages */
console.log('content script');
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    /* If the received message has the expected format... */
    if (msg.text && (msg.text == "report_back")) {
        /* Call the specified callback, passing
           the web-pages DOM content as argument */
        sendResponse(document.all[0].outerHTML);
    }
});
```

I didn't see any kind of activity when I click on the chrome icon on browser.What are the right process to get the DOM content from the open tab and manipulate.

Comment: Are you looking for the activity in the right console (background page console)? Did you reload the page after reloading the extension (since content scripts are only injected after navigation happens, not in currently open tabs)?

Comment: I checked in both inspect popup ( right click on icon) and background page from 'chrome://extension' page but none of this is working. I have write console in both JS file for that.

Comment: I stuck in somewhere very basic thing. I checked many SO post and surf many wesbite but still didn't get where to write the code so that I can work and debug too. :\

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Browser Action Popup and icon switch does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316974/chrome-browser-action-popup-and-icon-switch-does-not-work)

Comment: If you really need the popup, you need to work around that limitation; otherwise, remove the popup.

Comment: I want to show the manipulated DOM data in popup.html, that's why I added. are background js and popup js are equivalent in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64240/discussion-between-xan-and-diecho).