# Can't shoot a response every time extension button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm just trying to get a response every time the extension button is clicked. So like with AdBlock how this comes down

[image]

But instead I'm just trying to do a `console.log()` every time the button is clicked without any visible popups.

I've tried this so far

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.directive) {
        case "popup-click":
            // execute the content script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { // defaults to the current tab
                file: "real.js", // script to inject into page and run in sandbox
                allFrames: true // This injects script into iframes in the page and doesn't work before 4.0.266.0.
            });
            sendResponse({}); // sending back empty response to sender
            break;
        default:
            // helps debug when request directive doesn't match
            alert("Unmatched request of '" + request + "' from script to background.js from " + sender);
        }
    }
);
```

Then my `real.js`

```
console.log("Yo");
```

But sadly I only get a `Yo` when it launches. Any ideas?

Comment: What is sending this message you expect?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `function(request, sender, sendResponse) {`? @Xan

Comment: That's the listener.

Comment: So there's nothing in my code checking for the actual click? @Xan

Comment: Any idea on how to add something to look for the actual click? @Xan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **don't have a popup** (nothing shows when you click the button), then there is an event that will fire when the button is clicked:

> [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked)
>
> Fired when a browser action icon is clicked. This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup.

To use:

```
// In your background script
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function() {
  // Do stuff
});
```

If, however, you **do have a popup**, then, as the docs mention, this event will not fire. Then your code is more appropriate: you just need to send a message from the popup and catch it in the background script whenever it is opened. See a full example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23317011/934239).