# Chrome extension - on click event

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I started to learn today how to make chrome extension. All i want it to do is alert when i press the extension button.

My manifest.json file:

```
{
"name": "BrowserActionExtension",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "icons/19x19.png",
        "38": "icons/38x38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "That's the tool tip",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

i tied couple of things. The first was to run a script in the popup.html. but i read that i can't use inline scripts. My popup.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>

<body>
    Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

and my script file:

```
<script>
console.log("clicked");
alert("hey");
</script>
```

none of them works, no alert and it doesn't write into the console.

last thing i tried was to use: chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener
I used in background script, i figured out it works once when the extension starts to work (didn't understand if it run for every tab or once i open the browser).

```
function dostuff() {
  console.log("HEY")
  alert("FDS");
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(dostuff);
```

How can i alert when the extension is pressed?

Thank you for your help and time

Comment: Alert-upon-click? The method at the bottom of your question looks good. Your other method does not work because you've got HTML tags in a .js file. [Inspect the popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging#inspect-popup) and you would have seen a syntax error being reported in the console.

Answer (score 3):

1) You should not wrap the *contents* of an included JavaScript file in `<script>` tag.

Remove it, and your example should work.

Oh, and by the way, that `console.log("clicked");` will output into popup's own console. You can examine (and see the error about your code) by right-clicking the button and selecting "Inspect popup".

2) Your code in the background does not work, because the event does not fire while you're using a popup page. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23317011/934239) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much! all of it worked. The script is working, I can see the log AND the click is working too. Amazing, thank you for your answer